# Adding history support to simple jQuery AJAX navigation

Tags: jquery, ajax, bookmarks, browser-history

I am trying to add history support to my jQuery AJAX navigation, but since I don't know jQuery that well, I can't figure out how to do it. The following script replaces a  in the current document with a  from another document - thereby changing the content of the page. How can I improve the script to support browser history and bookmarks? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//References  
var loading = $("#loading");  
var container = $("#container");  
var link;  

//Manage click events  
$("a.ajax-links").click(function(e){  
    //prevent default action  
    e.preventDefault();  

    //show the loading bar  
    showLoading();   

    //define the target and get content then load it to container  
    link = $(this).attr("href") + " #content";  
    container.load(link, hideLoading);
});  

//show loading bar  
function showLoading(){  
    loading  
    .css({visibility:"visible"})  
    .css({opacity:"1"})  
    .css({display:"block"})  
    ;  
}  
//hide loading bar  
function hideLoading(){  
    loading.fadeTo(1000, 0);  
};
```

});

Comment: Have you tried http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/ ?

Comment: The demo shown has links like: <a href="#1">load 1.html</a> , so it doesn't work without javascript - mine does, so I'm looking for something that is both degradable and support history and bookmarks.

Answer (score 4):

Try [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) with [ajaxify](https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify) - it'll use the HTML5 History API so it modifies the URLs directly rather than using hashes <sup>[read why hashes aren't ideal here](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling)</sup>, and the gist will handle your links and ajax for you.

Comment: i get a 404 on the gist, bc. of new gist url structure, update link please.